# Creepify text - Combining characters

Tags: ios, unicode, nsstring

I want to create creepify text in my app with js code (creepify())
https://github.com/combatwombat/Lunicode.js/blob/master/lunicode.js

website using this js code: http://lunicode.com/creepify

My problem is when i try to combine characters, the result is'nt like in website.

I try to create 3 NSMutableArray

```
NSMutableArray *diacriticsTop;
NSMutableArray *diacriticsMiddle;
NSMutableArray *diacriticsBottom;
```

and store value like this

```
for (int i = 768; i <= 789; i++) {
    [diacriticsTop addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]];
}

for (int i = 790; i <= 819; i++) {
if (i != 794 && i != 795) {
    [diacriticsBottom addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]];
    }
}
...
```

then i convert creepify() in js code to

```
- (NSString *)creepifyString:(NSString *)inputString
{
    BOOL isTop = YES;
    BOOL isMiddle = YES;
    BOOL isBottom = YES;
    NSInteger maxHeight = 15;
    NSInteger randomization = 100;

    NSMutableString *outputString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    unichar output = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < inputString.length; i++) {
    unichar c = [inputString characterAtIndex:i];
    if (isMiddle) {
        NSNumber *temp = diacriticsMiddle[lroundf(drand48()*diacriticsMiddle.count)];
        c = c + (unichar) temp;
    }
    // Top
    if (isTop) {

        // Put up to this.options.maxHeight random diacritics on top.
        // optionally fluctuate the number via the randomization value (0-100%)
        // randomization 100%: 0 to maxHeight
        //                30%: 70% of maxHeight to maxHeight
        //                 x%: 100-x% of maxHeight to maxHeight
    int diacriticsTopLength = diacriticsTop.count - 1;
    for (int count = 0,
             len = maxHeight - drand48()*((randomization/100)*maxHeight); count < len; count++) {
            NSNumber *temp = diacriticsTop[lroundf(drand48()*diacriticsTopLength)];
            c = c + (unichar) temp;
        }
    }


    // Bottom
    if (isBottom) {
        int diacriticsBottomLength = diacriticsBottom.count - 1;
        for (int count = 0,
             len = maxHeight - drand48()*((randomization/100)*maxHeight); count < len; count++) {

            NSNumber *temp =diacriticsBottom[lroundf(drand48()*diacriticsBottomLength)];
            c = c + (unichar) temp;
        }
    }

    output = output + c;
}

[outputString appendFormat:@"%C", output];

NSLog(@"%@", outputString);

return outputString;

}
```

Comment: What's your exact issue?

Comment: http://lunicode.com/creepify <-- you can go to this website to create creepify text and see the result
The result text created in my app not like the result text in this website.

Comment: I saw what you want, but what I like, would be to see what you have with your code. Any screenshot could be interesting.

Comment: It usually combines my input text to Chinese characters :(
example: i input "qaz", output is one random Chinese character